# Admob Ads Stops on 0 seconds remaining

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I`m using ad mob rewarded ad in my android game, so whenever the user watches an ad he will earn 10 coins, but when you run the game, the ad loads fine, then starts & displays video fine, but when the timer reaches 0 seconds remaining the video stops & you will never be rewarded, also if you tries to close the ad it says you will use your reward & gives you two choices, either you close the ad & lose the reward, or resume video that is stopped!!!!

Comment: is there an `ad finished playing`, kind of event you should be handling?

Comment: no there is onRewarded method